# Is there any further consequence of redefining the keyword `private` as `public`?

Tags: c++

IN some cases we need to access its internal methods and members from eg a unit test.

Say for example

```cpp
// MyClass.h
class MyClass {
public: 
  MyClass() : value(-1) {}
  int internal_value() { return value; }  // << this is only used in test/debug
private: 
  int value; // internal 
};
```

But sometimes we don't want to (or it's very convenient not to) create friend classes explicitly nor add extra methods to the class.

In those cases it is easier to redefine `private` as `public` and then proceed inspecting the

```cpp
#define private public
#include "MyClass.h"
TEST(MyClass,value) {
   MyClass m;
   EXPECT_EQ(m.value,-1);
}
```

However that assumes that the side effect is just visibility and no functionality is going to be changed because of it.

So the question is: is there any side effect of redefining `private` to `public` **other than**  visibility itself? Anything that can affect the ABI, naming, passing conventions, linking, behavior?

Comment: I've done this private => public monkey patch before for a temporary fix and it will probably work, the C++ language spec does *not* guarantee that all the fields will be laid out the same (even though in reality they probably will be).

Comment: On my compiler, #defining a reserved word causes a compiler error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/325748/17034

Comment: @PaulSanders Interesting: Which one?

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica I think it was Xcode 13 (aka Apple clang something or other).

Comment: There are legal ways to access a private member, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22624503/how-to-get-a-file-descriptor-from-a-stdbasic-ios-for-clang-on-os-x

Comment: iirc, this doesn't work in MSVC. It adds private/public to its name mangling, so you end up with undefined references if the implementation is in a source file.

Comment: @PaulSanders You can use a `#pragma` to disable that error in Clang, I believe?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Could well be, I didn't investigate.  I just fixed my dodgy #define

Comment: Note: I don't recommend C-style casts, but there *is* one thing they do that C++ casts cannot do. They ignore access specifiers and can be used to get around `public`/`private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the question is: is there any side effect of redefining private to public other than visibility itself? Anything that can affect the ABI, naming, passing conventions, linking, behavior?

You might run in several issues (at least pedantically):

- Layout might change:

  ```
  struct AllSameVisibility
  {
      int a;
      int b;
      int c;
  }; // Layout is guaranteed to be as-is

  struct MixedVisibility
  {
  public:
      int a;
  protected:
      int b;
  private:
      int c;
  }; // Layout might be reordered
  ```

  turning one visibility into another might turn a mixed visibility into a class with identical visibility.
- ODR violation. definition should be identical (tokens and "meaning" (mainly overload resolution) )

  so, having both

  ```
  struct A {
  private:
      int a;
  };
  ```

  and

  ```
  struct A {
  public:
      int a;
  };
  ```

  in 2 different TUs (Translation units) make the program ill-formed NDR.

Comment: Ok I think this answer addresses the question posed, at least in part - I understand that might be more issues involved. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The C++ standard forbids redefining a keyword (such as `public` or `private`). Here is a quote from [`[macro.names]/2`](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/macro.names#2) (emphasis mine), from the current working draft:

> A translation unit shall not `#define` or `#undef` names **lexically identical to keywords,** to the identifiers listed in Table 4, or to the *attribute-tokens* described in `[dcl.attr]`, except that the names `likely` and `unlikely` may be defined as function-like macros (`[cpp.replace]`).

Comment: This doesn't mean much by itself. All modern compilers either accept this as is, or (in case of Clang) if you add a `#pragma` or compiler flag to silence warning/error.

Answer (score 3):

This may not be a direct answer to your question.  But probably some stuff to consider.

It's likely better to just explicitly declare your unit test or UT function a friend of the class:

```
class MyClass {

friend class MyClassTest;     // if your UT is its own class
friend void MyClass_Test();   // if your UT is a standalone function

public: 
  MyClass() : value(-1) {}
private: 
  int value; // internal 
};
```

You don't even need to include the actual declarations of these classes and functions in `MyClass.h`.

Some folks oppose this because it means polluting the product code with a test hook. When in reality, it doesn't change the compiled code or the contract of the class. It just allows the test code to access the internals without a compilation error. It's the cleanest hack of all to enable test code to get access to the internals of the class.

Alternatively, an outdated way of allowing test code access to internals is to declare the private members as protected.

```
class MyClass {
public: 
  MyClass() : value(-1) {}
protected: 
  int value; // internal 
};
```

Then in test code, you have a class that inherits from the above:

```
class MyClassUT : public MyClass
{
public:
    int getInternalValue() {return value;}
};
```

Then your unit tests work on the derived class

```
TEST(MyClass,value) {
   MyClassUT m;           // create derived class
   EXPECT_EQ(m.getInternalValue(),-1);
}
```

Comment: Good answer.  This fits the description of "doing the job properly"